# Why can I pass a callback function without quotation marks in PHP5?

Tags: php

I use the callback function without quotation marks, although it returns an error, it can be executed normally.

```
function fc($v) {
    echo $v + 1;
}

$a = [2, 4];
array_map(fc, $a); // <-- this works! notice how fc is not a string.
// output: 35
```

Although it seems useless, I want to know why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP converts undefined constants to strings automagically.**

If you let PHP execute this:

```
echo my_undefined_constant . " is a " . gettype(my_undefined_constant);
```

PHP will complain, a lot, but eventually my_undefined_constant will be the string "my_undefined_constant":

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant my_undefined_constant - assumed 'my_undefined_constant' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
  136.9851     395312   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Warning: Use of undefined constant undefined_constant - assumed 'undefined_constant' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
  136.9851     395312   1. {main}() php shell code:0

my_undefined_constant is a string  <---
```

But, as a result of undefined constants being converted to string literals, this will work:

```
php > echo call_user_func(strlen, 'test123');

Warning: Use of undefined constant strlen - assumed 'strlen' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
  258.5445     395240   1. {main}() php shell code:0

7 <---
```

This behavior is obviously highly questionable, and that's why implicitly converting undefined constants to string literals [has been deprecated since PHP 7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-bareword-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Its php feature that for warning, notice errors it displays them but continue executing script.

In similar manner though it has thrown error(warning) array_map function did its job.